# How to universalize $\text{Prov}(\ulcorner y < K(x)\urcorner) \to y < K(x)$ in a paper of Kikuchi

Tags: logic, peano-axioms, incompleteness, kolmogorov-complexity

In Kikuchi's paper [Kolmogorov complexity and the second incompleteness theorem](http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/%7Ekyodo/kokyuroku/contents/pdf/0912-3.pdf) he defines for $\Sigma_1$ binary predicates $R(x, y)$ the condition

$$ \Gamma_{1}(R) \Leftrightarrow \forall x\forall y(R(x, y) \to y < K(x)), $$

where $K(x)$ is the Kolmogorov complexity of $x$. He also mentions a lemma:

> For any $\Sigma_1$-sentence in the language of arithmetic:
>
> $PA \vdash \text{Con}(\text{PA}) \to (\text{Prov}(\ulcorner\neg\phi\urcorner) \to \neg\phi)$

Then he states that $\text{PA} \vdash \text{Con}(\text{PA}) \to \Gamma_{1}(\text{Prov}(\ulcorner y < K(x)\urcorner))$ follows immediately from the fact that $y < K(x)$ is the negation of a $\Sigma_{1}$ formula and the previous lemma.

I can see why we obviously get from the lemma each individual instance of $\text{Prov}(\ulcorner y < K(x)\urcorner) \to y < K(x)$ with $x, y$ replaced by natural numbers, but I don't see how to universalize this to the claim $\forall x \forall y (\text{Prov}(\ulcorner y < K(x)\urcorner) \to y < K(x))$, which is what we're after. The above lemma applies to individual sentences only.

What am I missing?

Comment: I may be wildly off the mark here, but isn't the universal quantification of a $\Pi_1$ sentence still a $\Pi_1$ sentence?

Comment: @Nagase I'm not sure what you mean. It could be missing something entirely trivial for sure! My problem is this: I can leverage the lemma to get things like $\text{Prov}(\ulcorner 777 < K(31415)\urcorner) \to 777 < K(31415)$, or whatever, but how do I get the universal? I cannot plug $K(x) \leq y$ as $\varphi$ into the lemma, since it's not a sentence. Does that make any sense?

Comment: Actually, I now think the issue is simpler: $y < K(x)$ is, according to Kikuchi, the negation of a $\Sigma_1$ formula, so we have $\mathsf{PA} \vdash \mathsf{CON(PA)} \rightarrow (\mathsf{Prov}(\ulcorner y < K(x) \urcorner) \rightarrow y < K(x))$ by the lemma. But then, it's a rule of logic that, if $x, y$ are not free in the antecedent, we may apply universal generalization to the consequent. So we're done.

Comment: @Nagase Sure, but $y < K(x)$ is not a sentence, so the lemma wouldn't apply, right?

Comment: @Nagase Hey, maybe you're interested in this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3822291/79127 . I've put up a nice bounty :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the text is using the lemma (arithmetized $Σ_1$-completeness of PA) for $Σ_1$-formulae rather than just sentences. Originally, I had thought that the generalized version could be easily proven from the specialized one, but I made a careless mistake. Now I believe that it cannot be proven in such a way.
$
\def\pa{\text{PA}}
\def\prov{\text{Prov}}
\def\prf{\text{Proof}}
\def\code#1{\ulcorner#1\urcorner}
\def\num#1{\underline{#1}}
\def\vv{\vec{v}}
$

First I shall give the generalized theorem and an outline of its proof. I shall use the provability modal operator where $⬜φ$ is some sentence that says "$φ$ is provable after its free variables have each been substituted by a numeral encoding its value". For example $⬜( \ ∀x{<}k\ ( \ x·x<k·x \ ) \ )$ expands to $\prov(\code{ ∀x{<}\num{k}\ ( \ x·x<\num{k}·x \ ) })$.

**Theorem**: Take any $Σ_1$-formula $φ$ with free variables $\vv$. Then $\pa ⊢ ∀\vv\ ( \ φ→⬜φ \ )$.

*Proof*: (Work with a deductive system for FOL that permits proving formulae with free variables, which are implicitly universally quantified.) Let $ψ$ be a formula equivalent to $φ$ that is in prenex normal form with only bounded universal quantifiers and with matrix in disjunctive normal form. We can assume that every literal in $ψ$ is "$x+y=z$" or "$x·y=z$" for some variables/numerals $x,y,z$, by trichotomy and using $x<y ≡ ∃d\ ( \ x+d+1=y \ )$ and de-nesting function-symbols. (For example, $x·y<z·z$ $≡ ∃a,b,c,d\ ( \ x·y=a ∧ a+1=b ∧ z·z=c ∧ a+d=c \ )$.) Then it suffices to show that $\pa ⊢ ψ→⬜ψ$, because $\pa ⊢ φ→ψ$ and $\pa ⊢ ⬜( \ ψ→φ \ )$. Note that:
  **(1)** $\pa ⊢ x+y=z → ⬜( \ x+y=z \ )$, for any variables/numerals $x,y,z$. [By induction.]
  **(2)** $\pa ⊢ x·y=z → ⬜( \ x·y=z \ )$, for any variables/numerals $x,y,z$. [By induction.]
  **(3)** $\pa ⊢ ⬜α∧⬜β → ⬜( \ α∧β \ )$, for any formulae $α,β$.
  **(4)** $\pa ⊢ ⬜α∨⬜β → ⬜( \ α∨β \ )$, for any formulae $α,β$.
  **(5)** $\pa ⊢ ∃x\ ( \ ⬜α \ ) → ⬜( \ ∃x\ ( \ α \ ) \ )$, for any formula $α$ and variable $x$.
      [Because $\pa ⊢ (⬜α)[x{:=}c] → ⬜( \ α[x{:=}c] \ )$.]
  **(6)** $\pa ⊢ ∀x{<}t\ ( \ ⬜α \ ) → ⬜( \ ∀x{<}t\ ( \ α \ ) \ )$, for any formula $α$ and variable $x$ and term $t$.
      [By induction with respect to $t$, since $\pa ⊢ ∀x{<}t\ ( \ α \ ) ∧ α[x{:=}t] ↔ ∀x{<}t{+}1\ ( \ α \ )$.]
By induction on the logical structure of $ψ$, using (1) and (2) on the literals in the matrix of $ψ$ and then (3) to (6) repeatedly, we obtain the desired claim.

In case you want a reference for the generalized lemma, I managed to find it in Rautenberg's "A Concise Introduction to Mathematical Logic" in Theorem 2.1 under Section 7.2 on "The Provable $Σ_1$-Completeness". Rautenberg did not clearly indicate disparity between the generalized and the specialized versions, but I feel that there is no easy way to bootstrap, because the induction I used in the above proof has parameters arising from those free variables.

Comment: Thanks your help so far, but unfortunately I don't understand your explanation yet. The "specialized lemma", to be absolutely precise, is $\text{PA} \vdash \varphi \to \square_\text{PA} \varphi$ for $\Sigma_1$-sentences $\varphi$. How does that give you $\text{PA} + \varphi \vdash \square_\text{PA}  \forall x \varphi(x)$?

Comment: @Jori: Thanks for pointing out my error. I have changed my mind about it being provable from the specialized version, but I cannot be sure about my belief. I also included a reference in case you want one.

Comment: Why does $\mathbf{PA} \vdash t = u \to \bar{t} = \bar{u}$ mean? Are $t, u$ variables or constants? If the latter, I don't think an inductive proof like this can work, because you will have to deal with situations where $t, u$ are variables (it's a correct atomic formula). In either case I don't understand what you mean with $\bar{t}, \bar{u}$.

Comment: @Jori: "$\underline{t}$" means the result of substituting the free variables in $t$ with numerals encoding their values, which is definable over PA in the same way that "$⬜φ$" is. For example, if $k,m$ are variables then within PA the *definable string* $\underline{k+m}$ is "$\underline{k}+\underline{m}$". For example, PA proves that ( PA proves "$\underline{k}+\underline{m} = \underline{k+m}$" ) by induction and so PA proves ( if $k+m=n$ then PA proves "$\underline{k+m}=\underline{n}$" ) as claimed. This generalizes to arbitrary terms by induction on the term construction.

Comment: I'm not completely positive yet whether I understand you. Let's take $t = x + y$ and $u = y + x$, then concretely what PA-formulas represent $x+y = y+x \to \overline{x+y} = \overline{y+x}$, and what about $x+y = y+x \to \square(x+y = y+x)$? What are those theorems that you say PA proves?

Comment: @Jori: In that example (1) states that PA proves ( if $x+y = y+x$ then PA proves "$\underline{x}+\underline{y} = \underline{y}+\underline{x}$" ). The example I gave was that (1) states that PA proves ( if $x+y = z$ then PA proves "$\underline{x}+\underline{y}=\underline{z}$" ). I think all this underline syntax is confusing, even for me. Let's use precise string manipulating syntax; let $num(k)$ be the numeral string encoding natural $k$. Then my example was that (1) states that PA proves ( if $x+y=z$ then PA proves the formula $num(x)$+"+"+$num(y)$+"="+$num(z)$ ). Clear enough?

Comment: It's not your fault that the underline syntax is confusing, because there are essentially 3 levels here... In my last comment I am explicitly using string manipulation to avoid confusing encoding at the middle or outer level.

Comment: Yes, that's what I understood as implicit. I can understand how the bar notation makes sense within the scope of $\square$, but I'm still not sure then what you mean when you say in (1) "because, $\mathbf{PA} \vdash t=u \to \bar{t} = \bar{u}$". Or am I talking nonsense ;) ?

Comment: @Jori: I realized I can not only clarify that part but also shorten the proof by constraining the literals in the matrix of the prenex normal form. Please see if you can understand it now! You can use the same trick to prove my original claim, but the proof is easier if we use this approach as we can subsume any added existential quantifiers by the quantifier chain.

Comment: @Jori: So... Have you understood my answer now? =)

Comment: I will look at it at some point, am a bit busy now. But I loaned the Rautenberg book and it got all the details that are usually skipped in accounts of Gödel's second theorem (even in good books like Smith's!). So I appreciate your answer and I shall accept it.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're right, that the argument given isn't correct. However, it's wrong for a right reason (?) - the lemma itself can be substantially strengthened.

I'll phrase it this way:

> $\mathsf{PA}$ proves that $\mathsf{PA}$ is $\Sigma_1$-complete. That is, $\mathsf{PA}\vdash$ "For every $x$, if $x$ is a code for a $\Sigma_1$ sentence then $\Sigma_1True(x)\implies Prove_{\mathsf{PA}}(x)$."

We can massage this a bit to get the following:

> $\mathsf{PA}$ proves "If $\mathsf{PA}$ is consistent and $x$ is a code for a true $\Sigma_1$ sentence, then $\neg Prov_{\mathsf{PA}}(Neg(x))$."

Here "$Neg$" is the usual formula defining the map $\ulcorner\varphi\urcorner\mapsto\ulcorner\neg\varphi\urcorner$. (For simplicity I'm treating a defined function as a new function symbol; it would be more proper to write "$\forall y(Neg(x,y)\implies \neg Prov_{\mathsf{PA}}(y))$," but that's annoying and doesn't actually add clarity.)

Now there's one final trick: the **substitution operation** $Sub(x,y,z)$. This is the usual formula defining the map $(\ulcorner\varphi\urcorner, n)\mapsto\ulcorner\varphi(\underline{n})\urcorner$. Within $\mathsf{PA}$ we have that if $x$ is a code for a $\Sigma_1$ formula and $Sub(x,y)$ then $y$ is a code for a $\Sigma_1$ sentence. This gives us:

> $\mathsf{PA}$ proves "If $\mathsf{PA}$ is consistent, $x$ is a code for a $\Sigma_1$ *formula*, and $y$ is such that $\Sigma_1True(Sub(x,y))$, then $\neg Prov_\mathsf{PA}(Neg(Sub(x,y)))$."

And when unwound this gets us (a bit more than) what we want: that $\mathsf{PA}$ proves "If $\mathsf{PA}$ is consistent then for every $x$ which is a $\Sigma_1$ formula code, each substitution instance of $x$ which $\mathsf{PA}$ disproves is in fact false."

Comment: It seems your "e.g. here" is missing a link. But can I just check with you, your version is equivalent to mine (for formulae), right? Mine implies yours because $Σ_1True$ is itself $Σ_1$. Yours implies mine because for any $Σ_1$-formula $φ$, PA proves that if $φ$ then $Σ_1True(\ulcorner φ\urcorner)$. Correct?

Comment: Anyway, do you know of a theory $T$ extending $PA^-$ such that $T$ proves itself $Σ_1$-complete for sentences but not arbitrary formulae? If there is, it would explain why I feel that we cannot easily get the formula version from the sentence version. But if not, then is there a simple trick to bootstrap, or is there a reason it is not easy to do so?

Comment: Hmm did you get my comments?

Comment: Noah, I think you missed a link at "See e.g. here." Also, "Within PA we have that if x is a code for a $\Sigma_1$ formula and Sub(x,y) then y is a code for a $\Sigma_1$ sentence" seems to be phrased confusingly.

Comment: More importantly, is there a relatively easy way to get from the theorem on sentences Kikuchi gives to the much more general theorem you list? Or is the proof of the latter altogether different?

Comment: @Noah did you get these comments? I want to accept your answer, but it would be good if you could incorporate my and user21820's comments. (Probably you're too busy, but I'm not sure what's the most appropriate way to give you a subtle reminder; please let me know if I'm doing it wrong, I've quite recently started to use this platform more often and don't know all the etiquette yet; at any rate, I want to thank you for all the help you provide out here, it's sincerely appreciated!)

Comment: I've removed the empty link for the time being. I hope you do find a reference eventually to put in, but anyway @Jori, I think it's clear that Noah's version follows from my version, which is also stated in Rautenberg (for which I've given you a reference in my post). So maybe there's no need for a second reference after all.